# Where to find current Bixby (Viv) Library Capsules versions?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

In my capsule I'm using `viv.image`, imported in `capsule.bxb` as

```
capsule-imports {
  import (viv.image) {
  as (image) version (2.12.1)
}
```

and since the last update I get a deprecation-warning `WARN-DEPRECATED`

[image: Deprecation warning]

I've updated it to the version I found [here in the Bixby Dev Guide](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library). It seems however that the versions specified there are just the minimum versions, not the current ones.

**Where can I find the current versions for the Viv Library Capsules?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, please ignore WARN_DEPRECATED. You will need to update library version if there is ERROR_DEPRECATED.

The link you provided is the correct place for [latest library version](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library).

Our internal team is working on a final solution. 
Current market place review is not gated by WARN_DEPRECATED.